# Querying for non existing record, returns null with HTTP 200

Tags: mysql, sql, rest, api, mule

I am perplexed a bit. I execute a simple `SELECT` query to MySQL DB for a record, which does not exist and get a HTTP 200 response with null for every element. Query is executed via RESTful API, which is still being developed by me. Maybe I missed something, for example, a definition of a response code?

DB

[image]

Query

`SELECT *
FROM csv_data.data
WHERE id = 20`

Response (HTTP 200 OK)

`{
    "id": null,
    "purchase": null,
    "price": null,
    "date": null,
    "notes": null
}`

API RAML

`/{purchaseId}:
    uriParameters:
      purchaseId:
        type: string
        description: Id of a purchase
        required: true
        example: "4"
    get:
      displayName: Get a single purchase
      description: Gets a single record of purchase
      responses:
        200:
          description: Status 200
          body:
            application/json:
              type: Purchase
              example: !include examples/get_purchase_example.json
        400:
          description: Status 400
          body:
            application/json:
              type: Error`

DB schema

[image]

Shouldn't I get HTTP code 404 or 400?

Comment: So, what do you do with the query response? It's nice that A to Z doesn't work, but without knowing what happens in between, people can't really help.

Comment: Sorry about this. As I am working with Mule, I use DataWeave Transformer to transform the message. Thats why I get this kind of response (nulls). Without the Transformer (**nothing** in between A and Z) I get - `org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.object.ManagedCursorIteratorProvider$ManagedCursorIterator@64a9db95`. Yet it still says that everything went okay - HTTP 200. When I use DataWeave Transformer to transform this message into readble format (from java to json), I get an empty object - `[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a naive world, yes, a 404 would be 'logical'. In the real world of 3rd parties, deadlines, inaccurate documentation and 'tactical solutions' the 404 error message would be perceived as a client/service being broken, since it's impossible to distinguish between "the server is missing", and "the result is missing".

200 with an empty response is a nice and smooth way of implementing "I am here, but what you asked for is not"

Comment: So this kind of response should be regarded as normal response, nothing unusual (started working at first programming job a few months ago)?

Comment: Uh huh, totally normal. An empty 200 is often better than a 404, since 404 implies the service isn't there.

Comment: Okay, that is good to know. I was convinced that if a record you query for does not exist, you should get one of the 4xx codes.

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP status of 400 means Bad Request.

An HTTP status of 404 means Not Found.

Neither of those are applicable for your case, because your request correctly reached the API expected to be reached and executed the function expected to execute.

There are no results to your MySQL request, so you have two options. The first is to return a 404 status code, the other is to implement a user-friendly logical error handle and apply it in the case when there is a logical error.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. My understanding of HTTP status codes was incorrect. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Tomeister you are welcome. If any of the answers solved the problem, you might consider accepting it as the correct answer, to help future visitors to your question.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that... I will regard @Davesoft answer as accepted as he beat you to it. Sorry :(

Comment: @Tomeister no problem :)